# Numerical methods question about Euler method solution notation?

Tags: numerical-methods

My nonlinear dynamics prof posted a solution to a problem about the Euler method.  I understand everything in his solution except for one statement he makes.  Say we are looking at the ODE $\dot x = f(x)$.  My prof made the statement that $$\ddot x = \dot f  = \dot x \dot f = f \dot f$$

I'm not sure why this is true - I definitely understand $\ddot x = \dot f$, because that comes from deriving the ODE, but I don't understand the following two parts.  This seems pretty important for finding an expression for a solution of the improved Euler method, and I want to make sure I understand it all before my final.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dots are derivatives with respect to $t$, he is applying the chain rule.  We have $$\ddot x(t)=\frac d{dt} \dot x(t)=\frac d{dt} f(x(t))=\dot f(x(t))\dot x(t)=\dot f(x(t))f(x(t))$$